# Two microprocessors with same machine language and different assembly language

Tags: microprocessor, assembly

I need to find two microprocessors that have same machine language but different assembly language.

Comment: As you very well know, this site is not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract.

Comment: You need to ask a question and not make a statement. Why fixate on assembly language. Why not use a higher level language then, the same MCU will work; one programmed with ASM and the other programmed with (say) C.

Comment: Good luck. Are you asking permission? If so, go ahead! If not, then you need to describe what the specific problem is in a way which is not just asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller There's nothing to stop you creating two assembly languages with different mnemonics, and even different syntax, which then compile to the same machine code.

Comment: @SimonB exactly my thought the second after I posted that comment, so I posted my answer and now deleted the comment.

Comment: Some processors have a few mnemonics that map to the same machine code. Sometimes for backward compatibility, sometimes for simplification. e.g. in PowerPC, NOOP is the same as ORing a register with itself.

Comment: That's easy. Use the Z80 with Zilog and Intel (8080) assemblers.

Comment: The Z80 is one nice example where even assemblers with the same "syntax" differ significantly: The company introducing it would not publish every instruction implemented. Some 3rd party (dis-)assemblers allow the undocumented instructions.

Answer (score 5):

Since "machine language words" and "assembly language words" map one to one (that's the purpose of assembler), what you ask for is trivial: just define that your second assembly language is exactly the same, but you prepend "XX" before every instruction. Tadah, two different assembly languages, corresponding to the same machine language.

Now you just need to buy two identical microcontrollers, paint a red dot on one of them and say "this one shall only be programmed in my own, XX-prepending assembly language".

Comment: This is true. I’ve done exactly this, only more elegantly. There are two general forms of assembly language. One is algebraic like “ACC = R0 + #0x2;” and the other is mnemonic as in “ADD R0, #0x2”. You then write a different assembler that accepts one or the other of the formats, and generate the same machine code. I don’t see the point for the question however.